# Overwriting Capybara methods to add logging

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I am using Capybara-Selenium in Ruby to run some automated tests and I want to add logging to the Capybara actions.

To do this I have overwritten the basic methods such as `click_on` and `has_text?`

These methods now look like this:

```
def has_text? text, options = {}
  if page.has_text? text, options
    @step.log :pass, "Looking for text \"#{text}\""
    true
  else
    @step.log :fail, "Looking for text \"#{text}\""
    false
  end
end

def has_field? locator, options = {}
  if page.has_field? locator, options
    @step.log :pass, "Looking for field \"#{locator}\""
    true
  else
    @step.log :fail, "Looking for field \"#{locator}\""
    false
  end
end
```

This works fine. However these methods are only useful when the web element being used has an ID. When there is no ID the element is found using the `find` method and then manipulated directly such as:

```
find(:css, 'some.locator').click
```

I want to add logging to these events as well. I could overwrite `find` and add generic logging, but that wont be very useful if I don't know what the element was used for after being found. I could add another parameter to my `find` method, but it would be clunky to write and read.

```
  find(:css, 'some.locator', 'click').click
```

Before I succumb to that solution, I wanted to check if there was any easier or better implementation I could be using? I was thinking along the lines of some kind of sudo-class that replaced the object being returned by `find`, and had logging on all its methods, or even better if I could attach an event of some kind to various methods that would tell my logger when it needs to add something... I have no idea if these approaches are possible, and/or feasible.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I would love to use rspec but my org already has a reporting framework in place they want to keep using.

Comment: I guess you could create an object that supports all the actions capybara does, and overwrite find to return that object rather than raising an error when it fails - then in that object you can do the failure logging when an action method is called --  It seems like a lot of work for what in the end may have dubious value